# Recommendation for prepaid SIM card in the Netherlands

Tags: cellphones, internet, netherlands

I will stay in the Netherlands for three months and I'm looking for a prepaid SIM card with a cheap data plan (like, 200 MB free per month). In Germany, there are lots and lots of offers like this, but due to my lack of Dutch I have not been able to find a website comparing plans.

Are there any websites which compare the plans, or any specific recommendations for certain plans? Websites in Dutch are fine, too.

Comment: sounds very similar to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/how-can-i-effectively-compare-data-plans-available-in-a-countr

Comment: I found exactly what I've looking for at KPN: Prepaid, microSIM, 200 MB internet plan. Other carriers might offer the same or cheaper plans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [bellen.com](http://www.bellen.com/mobiel/prepaid/vergelijking-tarieven/), but unfortunately Dutch only. The list of prepaid providers with Internet can be found [here](http://www.bellen.com/Content/Item.aspx?contentid=3209). It is in Dutch, but I hope the following translation of the table fields can help:

```
Aanbieder = Provider
Pakket = Package or Plan
Databundel = Data bundle (amount of Mb you can use for free)
Buitenbundel = what you pay if you go over your "Databundel"
Snelheid = speed
Prijs p/mnd = Price per month
```

Not all are prepaid. When it is, it is mentioned in the column "Pakket". Ignore Rabomobiel, Rabobank is a dutch bank and only available for bank customers.

Comment: You can also use google translate to read bellen.com.

Comment: Good point. The translation by googte translate is actually quite good. Except maybe the translation of Ben into Are