# Mobile Internet in the Netherlands

Tags: budget, cellphones, internet, netherlands, data-plans

I'm visiting the Netherlands for a week. I'd like to buy a SIM for my iPad to have internet access. What is the cheapest way? Cheapest carrier that offers 500MB-1GB? (with decent 3G coverage in Amsterdam)

Comment: Have you looked at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/recommendation-for-prepaid-sim-card-in-the-netherlands ? I am happy with Simyo coverage-wise (it's the KPN network) and it's quite cheap but I haven't done any systematic comparison and can't guarantee it's the cheapest. Wifi is quite common in bars, restaurants and many other venues so since saving money is apparently important to you, you might also consider foregoing the 3G connection.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Pay as You Go Sim with Data Wiki.  It's got an entire page devoted to the Netherlands:
http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Netherlands

Answer (score 3):

I'd get a Lebara SIM card, they can send it to you by post for free and then you can top-up online. [It's 1 GB for 10 euro](http://www.lebara.nl/mobiel-internet).

Comment: You can also buy it in street spots around any city in NL. The card is free, you just top up the data/calling credits. I am using Lebara for a 1 year already (came to NL for MSc studies) and it provides good level of coverage and internet speed.